# copy constructor...what is wrong?

Tags: c++

So my problem is this...when I am trying to allocate memory to a pointer, it fails.

This is my MatrixClass definition..

```
class MatrixClass
{
public:
    MatrixClass(int m, int n);
    MatrixClass(void);
    virtual ~MatrixClass(void);
    double getRead(int num1, int num2) const;
    double& getReadWrite(int num3, int num4);
    void set(int i,int j,double value);//set value at i,j to value
    MatrixClass(const MatrixClass &rhs);
    void assign(int M,int N);
    MatrixClass sum1(const MatrixClass& rhs) const;
    MatrixClass operator+(const MatrixClass& rhs);//overloading the + operator 
    MatrixClass operator-();
private:
    double* dataptr;
    int M;
    int N;
};
```

I am trying to do this..

```
MatrixClass BB;
BB = A + B;
```

So here is my overloaded + function..

```
MatrixClass MatrixClass::operator +(const MatrixClass &rhs)
{
    MatrixClass temp;
    //temp.M = this->M + rhs.M;
    //temp.N = this->N + rhs.N;
    for(int i = 0;i < M;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<N;j++)
        {
            temp.dataptr[i * N + j] = this->getReadWrite(i,j) + rhs.dataptr[i*N+j];
        }
    }   
    return temp;
}//end operator +
```

Once temp returns...it calls the copy constructor...passing temp as 'rhs' and 'this' would refer to 'BB'? (Am I right in thinking this?)

```
MatrixClass::MatrixClass(const MatrixClass &rhs)//copy constructor
{
    this->M = rhs.M;
    this->N = rhs.N;
    dataptr = 0;
    if(rhs.dataptr != 0)
    {
        dataptr = new double[M * N];//allocate memory for the new object being assigned to...
        // the line here where I try to allocate memory gives me an error.....Am I right in
        //thinking that this would be assigning memory to dataptr of 'BB'?? Values are assigned to //'M' and 'N' fine....
        int num = sizeof(double);
        memcpy(this->dataptr,rhs.dataptr,M*N*sizeof(double));   
    }
    else
    {
        this->dataptr = 0;
    }
}//end copy constructor
```

Also the error that i get is this... 'Unhandled exception at 0x75a0b727 in assignment.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x002af924..'

So basically the qestion I am asking is..why the hell is is the line where I am trying to allocate memory to 'dataptr' in the copy constructor giving me problems..it only does this when calling the copy constructor from the return value 'temp'..

Thanks!

Comment: What does your default constructor do? Does it initialize `M` and `N`? If it doesn't, then your program *possibly* invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: have you printed the value of M and N when it fails?

Comment: Thanks, this is my default constructor..

    MatrixClass::MatrixClass(void): M(4),N(5)
    {
    }

M and N can be assigned to with no problem in the copy constructor..just not the pointer..

Comment: @JamesHatton: That is it? It doesn't allocate memory for `dataptr`? You're using `dataptr` in `operator=` without even allocating memory for it.

Comment: Ok, the value of M and N is 4 and 5 (in that order

Comment: @JamesHatton: So your default constructor initializes `M` and `N`, but doesn't allocate memory for `dataptr`? That'll cause a crash for sure (or open a black hole, or run just fine... it's undefined behavior when you use it in `operator+`). Also, consider using `std::copy` over `memcpy`, since we're using C++ here.

Comment: "assignment.exe"?  Is this homework?

Comment: hope so... otherwise, save yourself and employer time and use an existing matrix library

Comment: @BenVoigt yes this is homework...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you have not implemented [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) properly. [In C++11, Rule of Five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11).

Long answer: you have not implemented `operator=`.  The compiler generated one is not enough for your case.

Apart from that my guess is that your default constructor doesn't allocate memory for `dataptr`. If so, then you're using `dataptr` in `operator+` without even allocating memory for it. That is the reason why your program crashes. Even if the default constructor allocates memory, the problem is still there as the value of `rhs.M` and `rhs.N` may be different from what you assume in the default constructor (which is, as you said, `4` and `5` respectively).

So allocate memory for `dataptr` in  `operator+`. Also, before allocation, you've to deallocate the memory which it may point to, and you also need to set `M` and `N` to the values of `rhs.M` and `rhs.N` respectively.

Comment: Hey, thanks...so are you saying that BB = A + B; is using the default assignment operator and not allocating any memory specifically for 'dataptr'?

Comment: @JamesHatton: Oops I meant `operator+`, but the default `operator=` is also a problem.

Comment: Nawaz you are correct...seems like a very silly thing when you look back...I have allocated memory for 'dataptr' in operator+ and it now works fine...thanks!

Comment: @JamesHatton: You must implement `operator=` also. It is necessary for your case.

Comment: Thanks also for the info about the Rule of three.having a read now.

Comment: @James: It's not `operator+` that should allocate, but the copy-assignment and copy-constructor.

Comment: Hmmm..so do I allocate memory in operator+ or not?..If I allocate memory in operator+ it works fine...although that leads me to ask...

When I did, MatrixClass(2,3)..this should initilize dataptr to a new double anyway...it is almost like it is losing it's scope when being  passed in to the copy constructor.

Comment: @JamesHatton: No. `operator+` should not allocate memory; it is constructor which should allocate memory, and you should pass the dimensions to the constructor. `operator+` should do only what it should do : `+`.

Answer (score 1):

No, James, you're wrong, when `operator+` returns the copy constructor will be called to covert local variable `temp` into a temporary anonymous object in the scope of the assignment operator. In the copy constructor, `this` will refer to this temporary variable, not BB.

Because the LHS already exists, it will not be "constructed" again when `operator+` returns, it will be "assigned", so you need to overload `operator=`.  (See [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/911-the-copy-constructor-and-overloading-the-assignment-operator/) for much more detail.)  The default `operator=` just makes a bitwise copy, so if you didn't overload operator=, the `dataptr` would be freed (we hope) in the destructor of the anonymous temporary object when it is destroyed as it goes out of scope (which is immediately after it is copied) and BB would be pointing to freed memory.  You would also leak any memory already allocated in BB as BB would not be destroyed before being assigned.  BB's `dataptr` would leak while the temporary object's `dataptr` would be freed twice.

So, although it kind of sucks that you end up allocating and copying memory three times, in order to make + and = work in all situations, you need to do the following:

- In `operator+` change `MatrixClass temp;` to `MatrixClass temp(rhs.M, rhs.N);` so that `temp.dataptr` is properly allocated and deallocated.
- As you are doing, in the copy constructor allocate new memory for `dataptr` and copy it over.
- Overload `operator=` so that it first checks for self-assignment `(this == &rhs)` and if it is not self-assigning, frees the existing `dataptr` and then allocates a new one and copies the `rhs`.

Comment: When I step through my code it does not call the assignment operator?

Comment: @James, you won't see calls to the default assignment operator.  If you overrode the assignment operator and it is not not being called, then you didn't override the assignment operator. :-)  Obviously the statement you wrote is an assignment.  Perhaps you got the function signature wrong?